# Recovering very large MySQL MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, myisam, data-recovery

For budgetary reasons I use MyISAM tables to store very large amounts of data. I recently had a server crash and one of my large tables (4 billion rows) crashed and I have been unable to repair it with a variety of repair methods (several different myisamchk options).

Is there a way to recover as many rows as possible of the data file and import it again into the db? Data was only added during the life of the table, so it should just be a matter of knowing the data file format, reading it and exporting to a text file, then importing it back into a clean table. I have been searching like crazy but haven't found anything to do this.

Comment: try to copy data from one table to another choosing good ranges of primary key . Here's a script that does that http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~percona-dev/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb/trunk/view/head:/fetch_data.sh

Comment: I hope the table has PK

Comment: The table is corrupt... so I can't run queries on it.

Comment: did you try point selects?

Comment: I have no idea what that is. I tried Googling and saw only references to a benchmarking tool made by Sysbench. Can you related what point selects are, and how they might be useful in this instance?

Comment: point select is a select by primary key. For example, SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 5

Comment: As I said above, the table is corrupt... so I can't run queries on it.

Comment: Did you recover the table?

Comment: Cannot recover it...